# Void within an ortho images when floating on 3D surface using ArcScene

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, 3d-analyst, arcscene, floating

I m trying to visualise an ortho photo on a 3D surface (tif). There is no problem for most ortho photos except one (see below photo), where there is a void within the ortho image. Both the ortho image and the 3D surface I m using is a single raster, so I cannot further mosaic them to avoid the problem.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How does the Ortho Imagery look in a 2D map? Is the original ortho showcase this white patch or it's just the 3D view triggering the behavior?

Comment: hi there, thanks for your reply! the Ortho Imagery looks totally fine in a 2D map (without any white patch and voids in ArcMap). I have totally no idea why this white patch only occurs in the 3D view on Arcscene.